# wkhtmltopdf - Even number of pages as output

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm looking for a way to make sure that the output from wkhtmltopdf always consists of an even number of pages, i.e. adding a blank page at the end of the pdf if the number of pages is uneven. If anyone has a good solutions for this I would be really happy

/J

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create the pdf, then check the page count and add one empty page with for example itext / itextsharp if necessary. Guessing page counts or lengths is very difficult.

Comment: I guess that could work, but i prefer not to include another third party SW besides wkhtmltopdf. If was enough problems including and tuning that program to my needs, so what I'm really after is a solution working with plain wkhtmltopdf, js, jquery, C# or similar.

Comment: Understood. I'll try to think of something else. Wkhtmltopdf page breaking is notorious. If your content is highly predictable, some content calculation could be done, but I it would require that your margins and page size are pretty much static. Some dudes have done page calculation with JS by calculating the content height (page fits ~1800px, my document height is ~6000px etc etc), but it is Very unperdictable in my content and I can't really recommend it before I have tried it myself.

Comment: In https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=168&q=table%20break there is some releated discussion and height calculations that might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your good comments but it seams I'm stuck now. I tried counting the pages in the footer with a script and that works perfectly ok. Then I did a MOD 2 operation on that count and found out if the number was uneven, also works fine. But when I tried adding a page-break-after: always; in the footer nothing happens, I guess it's because wkhtmltopdf never breaks the footer :-(. So what I would need at this stage is a way to manipulate the main document from the footer script so I could add my break there. Can I get access to the main document from the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP asked for a solution involving only wkhtmltopdf, I already had pdftk as part of my toolchain, so here's the concrete solution I used:

1. Use wkhtmltopdf to create the PDF
2. Count the number of pages with `pdftk input.pdf dump_data_annots`, which outputs the page count in a parseable output (`NumberOfPages: 3`)
3. Write an empty PDF to disk (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277967/545220) for a short and easy snippet of an empty PDF; adjust the page size as necessary)
4. Use `pdftk input.pdf blank.pdf cat output output.pdf` to create the final version with a blank page (if `input.pdf` has uneven pages)